# Can not find app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php to change pageConfig->setDescription on Magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento2

Can not find app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php to change pageConfig->setDescription on Magento 2.0.7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I try find vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View.php and replace
$this->pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
with
$this->pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr(strip_tags($product->getDescription()), 0, 255));

to fix tags description over on header

But not have any change